# kill pserve(Gunicorn) specific server from pyramid

Tags: linux, web-services, pyramid, kill, gunicorn

i use pyramid with pserve running Gunicorn like this:

```
pserve production.ini
```

production.ini

```
[server:main]
use = egg:gunicorn#main
host = 0.0.0.0
port = 8080
workers = 3
worker_class = gevent
daemon = true
```

and it returns the PID

```
Starting server in PID XXXXX.
```

but i can't kill it by running

```
# kill XXXXX
-bash: kill: (XXXXX) - No such process
```

or

```
# pserver --stop-daemon XXXXX
No PID File exists in pyramid.pid
```

till now, i've been using

```
pkill pserve
```

but now, i have multiple servers running, so it will kill all my servers.

how can i kill a specific running server?

Comment: Is the server actually running? Last time I tried `daemon=true` with paster using pserve or even gunicorn_paster. It was spawning a process and then died. Even when I specified the pid file where it should write the file, it wasn't doing anything.

Answer (score 2):

if the server is actually running, I'd try something like that.

```
ps -ax | grep pserv[e]
```

It will show all process with their pid on the first column. If something match what you are looking for. You can kill it. The `x` option should show the command line used to start the process. If you're lucky it will show that it was started in "that" directory or with "that" config file.

otherwise, it might be possible to check which process is listening to which port and getting its pid.